# First order ODE Substitution

Tags: calculus, ordinary-differential-equations

When we have a O.D.E that is neither linear or separable, we use substitution to find out what $y(x)$ is.

Does the choice of $v$ in substitution matter in outcome? The textbook primarily uses $v=\frac{y}{x}$, but never $v=\frac{x}{y}$, which leads me to think this is some type of convention. My knee-jerk response was that when we obtain $\frac{dy}{dx}$, it shouldn't matter whether $v = \frac{y}{x}$ or $\frac{x}{y}$, because the original O.D.E would reflect changes in $v$ accordingly.

However, when I was given a simple differential equation to solve:

> $2xy\frac{dy}{dx} = 4x^2 + 3y^2$

I was able to compute the correct answer much faster and efficiently when $v=\frac{y}{x}$ but struggled to do so with $v=\frac{x}{y}$.

Sorry if this is a silly question.

Comment: The key observation on this DE is that it is homogeneous of order 2. When a DE is homogeneous in this sense you may use either the substitution $y=ux$ or $x=uy$ to obtain a separable equation. It is not unusual for one of the two options to be the better choice in the sense that it leads to an easier solution.

Answer (score 0):

i don't think your question is silly. i guess if you see why the change variable $m = y/x$ or $1/m = x/y$ works for the homogeneous de like $$\frac{dy}{dx} = \frac{4x^2 + 3y^2}{2xy},\tag 1$$  then may be you can see the reason for this change of variable.

the homogenity of the de implies that the right hand side is constant on the lines $y = mx.$  that the slope at every point on this line is a constant and depends only on the slope and not on the individual coordinates $x$ and $y.$ now you can step forward or backward using the slopes instead of the usual steping forwrad or backward using the independent variable $x.$

i believe that is the reason for the use and effectiveness of the change variable.